# SFDX Scratch orgs are missing Chatter Plus/Chatter Only license

Tags: salesforcedx, profile, user, licenses, scratch-org

I need to create a user with "Chatter Plus/Chatter Only" license in my DX scratch org with this config:

```
{
  "orgName": "Demo Company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "PersonAccounts",
    "ForceComPlatform"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
      "chatterEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

But the option doesn't come up in the User Edit screen. What am I doing wrong?